# TfidfVectorizer in sklearn how to specifically INCLUDE words

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I have some questions about the `TfidfVectorizer`.

It is unclear to me how the words are selected. We can give a minimum support, but after that, what will decide which features will be selected (e.g. higher support more chance)? If we say `max_features = 10000`, do we always get the same? If we say `max_features = 12000`, will we get the same `10000` features, but an extra added `2000`?

Also, is there a way to extend the, say, `max_features=20000` features? I fit it on some text, but I know of some words that should be included for sure, and also some emoticons ":-)" etc. How to add these to the `TfidfVectorizer` object, so that it will be possible to use the object, use it to `fit` and `predict`

```
to_include = [":-)", ":-P"]
method = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=20000, ngram_range=(1, 3),
                      # I know stopwords, but how about include words?
                      stop_words=test.stoplist[:100], 
                      # include words ??
                      analyzer='word',
                      min_df=5)
method.fit(traindata)
```

### Sought result:

```
X = method.transform(traindata)
X
<Nx20002 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
 with 1135520 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], 
 where N is sample size
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are asking several separate questions. Let me answer them separately:

**"It is unclear to me how the words are selected."**

From the [documentation](https://github.com/mbatchkarov/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py):

```
max_features : optional, None by default
    If not None, build a vocabulary that only consider the top
    max_features ordered by term frequency across the corpus.
```

All the features (in your case unigrams, bigrams and trigrams) are ordered by frequency in the entire corpus, and then the top `10000` are selected. The uncommon words are thrown out.

**"If we say max_features = 10000, do we always get the same? If we say max_features = 12000, will we get the same 10000 features, but an extra added 2000?"**

Yes. The process is deterministic: for a given corpus and a given `max_features`, you will always get the same features.

**I fit it on some text, but I know of some words that should be included for sure, [...] How to add these to the TfidfVectorizer object?**

You use the `vocabulary` parameter to specify what features should be used. For example, if you want only emoticons to be extracted, you can do the following:

```
emoticons = {":)":0, ":P":1, ":(":2}
vect = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=emoticons)
matrix = vect.fit_transform(traindata)
```

This will return a `<Nx3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>' with M stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]`. Notice there are only 3 columns, one for each feature.

If you want the vocabulary to include the emoticons **as well as the `N` most common features**, you could calculate the most frequent features first, then merge them with the emoticons and re-vectorize like so:

```
# calculate the most frequent features first
vect = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=emoticons, max_features=10)
matrix = vect.fit_transform(traindata)
top_features = vect.vocabulary_
n = len(top_features)

# insert the emoticons into the vocabulary of common features
emoticons = {":)":0, ":P":1, ":(":2)}
for feature, index in emoticons.items():
    top_features[feature] = n + index

# re-vectorize using both sets of features
# at this point len(top_features) == 13
vect = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=top_features)
matrix = vect.fit_transform(traindata)
```

Comment: Though this does not consider the fact that `":-)"` is not a word? As far as I see it, these will be filtered out (0 stored elements).

Comment: Contrary to what I suspected, rather than looking at anything related to "token(ize)", the `analyzer` needs a different function if anyone is interested.